# Storage for KVM virtualization

Tags: storage, kvm-virtualization

I am looking into setting up 3 kvm hosts. Currently I am using local storage with mirrored drives raid 1 for images. I am also using raw images. I was wondering if this is against best practices and I will need to invest in the SAN unit or its acceptable to use local storage. I am running around 20 vms on each host , mostly web servers like cpanel.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

There are pros and cons to using DAS here.

Pros:

- DAS is cheap
- DAS is fast
- DAS is *easy*

Cons:

- If you lose a host, you have to restore those VMs from backup, unless you're mirroring them from local storage to remote storage
- You can't use most clustering technologies without shared storage. If you want to cluster VMs on different hosts for HA purposes, you generally need some form of shared storage anyway (not true for all tech, but required for many).
- Less flexible. You're limited to expanding storage by the number of slots in the server unless you get an external DAS enclosure. With SAN storage, most solutions allow you to just add an extra shelf, add it to a pool, and you're done.

---

So, in short, there's no real answer. Many large installations use SAN storage, and there's a reason for that. *But* no one can really answer this for your environment except you.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about KVM, but recent Hyper-V presentations for the new 2012 R2 vrsion have shown that MS is using DAS (Directly Attached Storage) on every node ;) SO, A SAN is clearly not needed for running larger farms of virtualization systems.

Obviously better have some good IO there - 20 machines starting etc. are nasty, IO wise.

Comment: That's just for presentation, though. I doubt they run production environments purely on DAS. In fact, I know that they have a substantial amount of NetApp storage there.

Comment: Why not? Noone says they do not use NetApp in teh backend - to store the VM's. They whole sysetm goes towards replicating state out. THe cost of a NetApp is not worth it in mos cases - put a Raid local. You should watch the presentation - it is HIGHLY interesting.

Comment: I haven't see the presentation that you're talking about. At the risk of taking this slightly off-topic, would you mind posting a link? :)

Comment: Oh my - there are so many. I Think it is hidden somewhere in here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/06/10/best-of-teched-2013-what-s-new-in-hyper-v-in-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx#.UbvTzflpm3A - MS is going heavily into offering people the ability to run their own cloud with the same tech as azure. Storage is a hot topic all along, thanks to the damn high cost of a scalable SAN. If not there, it is in one of those: http://cavarpe.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/teched-2013-storage-related-sessions/

Answer (score 1):

DAS is fine as long as you have no problem with the lack of flexibility coming with this sort of storage.
Many of our (our = the company I work for) customers even run virtualization hosts based on Ubuntu + KVM with RAID 5 disks (DAS) - so far we have had no problems here. We also mirror the data to another virtualization host so there is no problem with moving VMs to another system.

It always depends on the requirements you have.